# react-native-audio-recorder-player error Plugin with id "kotlin-android" not found. compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-audio-recorder-player'.

> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
> To Reproduce:
> I just updated react-native-audio-recorder-player from 3.0.11 to 3.3.3

Expected behavior:
Build project successfully.

Environment:

OS: macOS
OS version: 10.15.4
react-native version: 0.67.1
react-native-audio-recorder-player version: 3.3.3

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this

goto node_modules > react-native-audio-rcorder-player > android > build.gradle

add this line inside buildscript dependencies (below build gradle version)

```
    ` classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"`
```

Comment: I'm finding following the "post installation" instructions for the package works, no need to patch the package as suggested in this answer. See below.

Answer (score 1):

the standard way for resolving this error is adding below configuration to `android/build.gradle` of your RN project to enable `kotlin`. (as library post install steps states)

```
buildscript {
  ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
+     // Note: Below change is necessary for pause / resume audio feature. Not for Kotlin.
+     minSdkVersion = 24
      compileSdkVersion = 29
      targetSdkVersion = 29
+     kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'

      ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
  }
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
+     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
  }
...
```

I also added below code to `app/build.gradle` file of my RN project for resolving error `Invoke-customs are only supported starting with android 0 --min-api 26`

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: this works only for react-native versions < 0.69

Comment: The standard way, called-out by the [react-native-audio-recorder-player post installation](https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-audio-recorder-player) instructions work for react-native > 0.69, too.